# What are numbers with E in them called?

Tags: notation

I know that this is a very stupid question, and that I will get flamed for it, but I cannot find any information what-so-ever about it on the internet, because Google doesn't include some characters while querying.

What is a number with E in it called?

Ex: 41E+100

I understand that this is 41 followed by 100 zeros, but what is this type of notation called?

Comment: It's shorthand for scientific notation.

Comment: @AlexG. Well thank you very much!

Comment: More precisely, it's called "E notation."  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation

Comment: looks like IEEE floating point to me ...